# Major leak in my NSDateFormatter script

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

I used Instrument to check if I had any leaks in my script and it came with a couple particularly in my NSDateFormatter. It says I had it:

```
Leaked Object    #   Address         Size       Responsible Library   Responsible Frame
NSDateFormatter  70  < multiple >   1.09 KB    DAF                   +[XMLParser dateFromString:]
```

This is my method it points at and I cannot find any leak:

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *nsDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [nsDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date = [nsDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
    [nsDateFormatter release];
}
```

Can anybody help me with this one? I have no idea where to look this is my first time with Instruments.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler didn't warn about "unreachable statement" or the like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning date before releasing the formatter.

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *nsDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [nsDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date = [nsDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [nsDateFormatter release]; //Release here
    return date;
    //Code after a return does not get executed!!!
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make your `return` statement the last statement. As you have written it, `[nsDateFormatter release]` is never called, because the function is returning before it can execute that line.